# Runtime error while trying to load a dataset as a table in Snap.py

Tags: python, graph, dataset, network-analysis

I was trying to load co04_dist.txt from http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/cities/cities.html as a table in Snap.py

```
import snap

context = snap.TTableContext()
filename = "co04_dist.txt"

schema = snap.Schema()
schema.Add(snap.TStrTAttrPr("Col1", snap.atInt))
schema.Add(snap.TStrTAttrPr("Col2", snap.atInt))
schema.Add(snap.TStrTAttrPr("Col3", snap.atInt))
schema.Add(snap.TStrTAttrPr("Col4", snap.atInt))

table = snap.TTable.LoadSS(schema, filename, context, "\t", snap.TBool(False))
```

But all I get is the runtime error claiming that the application requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. It also says this in the shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\city.py", line 12, in <module>
table = snap.TTable.LoadSS(schema, filename, context, "\t", snap.TBool(False))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\snap.py", line 23070, in LoadSS
return _snap.TTable_LoadSS(*args)
RuntimeError: Execution stopped: Ss.GetFlds() == S.Len(), file c:\cygwin\home\rok\build\snap\snap-core\table.cpp, line 683
```

I have already ensured that the txt file is already in the same directory as the .py file.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to have this specification on top of the dataset for it to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztmib.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer? Right now it's barely useful. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer